# multiple Server for Wordpress on AWS web service

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, multiple-instances

i decided to install word press on amazon web service (AWS)
 we decided to use two server , 
1 one for application and 
2 one for database ,
in this way we can put the load balancing ,
the simple architecture based on this document

http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Web_Hosting_Best_Practices.pdf 
we already aware that currently amazon support using 
wordpress via EC2(virtual machine) and amazon (RDS) or via one server via the EBS . 
but what is our mined to using two server , one for word press engine, one for data base. 
in that way we can scale the system
i don t know where i should start and how to do it ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your asking, but IMO 2 dbs for a Wordpress install is overkill, but to is a way to. Scale.

Comment: i mean like AWs , put the word press on the EC2 and database on the RDS, but we want to  put on application server and database server.

Comment: Well RDS is a managed database server running on an EC2 instance with a special configuration. Unless you have a really specific application, I would always go for RDS instead of a self-hosted MySQL server on EC2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need of the application server.

You can get started with it in several ways.

1) If you wanna get into the nitty gritty details and get your hands dirty, go direct with the auto scaling + ec2 + rds - the best and most flexbile option although it will require more effort

2) Otherwise you can go with Elastic Beanstalk and let it create a container for your wordpress installation and take care of the ELB, AutoScaling, RDS and stuff.

In both cases there are plenty of resources on google that will help you accomplish that.

I wouldn't worry for an application server, I know the most Wordpress installations (if not all) works fine with the plain vanilla setup Web Server + DB Server - Do this and let AWS ddo the hard job for you and scale your environment "automagically"

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to run a webserver and a database on separate instances, you can be up and running in about ten minutes if you use [Cloudformation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) and the 2 server [wordpress template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/WordPress_Single_Instance_With_RDS.template).  To read up a bit about these templates, see [this page](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/)

Also, [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKljYgi2lQ0) might help.